# Section title formatting

Tags: sectioning

In the book I translate, some sections are optional and this is denoted by a star before section number .... for example, Section 3.5 with the Title A is not optional but Section 3.6 with the Title B is optional .. this gives the results

```
3.5 Title A and
*3.6 Title B
```

How can put a star before section number and how i can remove from the next (not optional) sections?

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation of `titlesec`, §4.3 `Variants`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bernard commented this is possible with the `titlesec` package. However, it is also easy to do without packages, which might be preferred if you don't want to use `titlesec` for some reason.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\optionalsection}[1]{%
\renewcommand\thesection{*\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%
\section{#1}%
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\optionalsection{Optional section}
\section{Third section}
\end{document}
```

Here a new command called `\optionalsection` is defined that first changes the section number format to a *, the chapter number, a dot, and the section number, then creates a section with this format, then resets the section number to the default format.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it would look nicer to code `\renewcommand\thesection{\llap{*}\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%`: the chapter number would till be at the left margin, and the star would be protruding into the left margin.